# Run Window Service from c# code without installing service

Tags: c#, service

I have folder path which contain window service. I want to invoke window service as normal exe and process. How to call the service exe from C# code. So that like normal exe, service exe will run only one time.

Comment: What is the *nature* of this service exe? Is it also written in .NET? Did you author it also?

Comment: I think the service has to be written in a way that specifically allows that.

Comment: Take a look at http://einaregilsson.com/run-windows-service-as-a-console-program/

Comment: No. I did not create the window service. I want to execute the window service by calling service exe from c# code(without installing the service)

Comment: Has this service logic in separate dll?

Comment: Yes. I have a folder which contain DLL and service exe which will be executed if we install as a service.

Comment: Not in DLL. it is inside service exe.

Answer (score 2):

I think your best shot is to refer to the documentation of the service. Some applications which normally run as a service have an option of running in a console mode when you specify a parameter. It could be '/c', '-c', '--console', or something completely different.